# How to remove numerical values from a text file with Notepad ++?

Tags: notepad++

I have one 1 GB sized file and I want to remove the count from names as in my below example.

**Original File Content Example**

```
 977014 michael
 963693 john
 924816 david
 819879 chris
 640957 mike
 602088 james
 584438 mark
 515686 jason
 503658 robert
 484403 jessica
 476643 sarah
 476289 jennifer
 466306 paul
 456588 brian
```

I want to remove the numbers from the file, and I need it to have only the name as in the below example.

**Expected Result Example**

```
michael
john
david
...
```

Comment: Regex. Something like: find - `\d+? (.+?)`; replace - `\1` (with ". matches newline" disabled). Or possibly `.+? (.+?)`.

Answer (score 5):

### Remove all numbers from a text document with Notepad++

From [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/) with the applicable text document opened, press <kbd>**`Ctrl`**</kbd>**`+`**<kbd>**`H`**</kbd>, in the **Find what** field type in **`[0-9]+`**, be sure to have all the options set as specified in the **Replace** window screen (or the **Notepad++ Options** screen shot) section below, and select the <kbd>**`Replace All`**</kbd> option.

- This works because the regular expression (**`[0-9]`**) followed by a plus symbol (**`+`**) means for it'll match one or more occurrences of the one character regex which are numerical values in this case, and those get **Replaced with** nothing so the numbers get removed just as needed.

---

### Notepad++ Options

[image]

- **Find what:** `[0-9]+`
- **Replace with:**  (blank/nothing/no spaces/empty)
- **Wrap around:** `Checked`
- **Search Mode:** `Regular expression`
- **Replace All:** `Press it`

**Before**

[image]

**After**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the numbers column is a constant width, you can simply hold down the ALT key while dragging a rectangle over the area you want to delete.  Once it's highlighted, just press either the delete key or the backspace key.  I guess that's not convenient if you have more than 100 or so lines, but it's great for small files.  This also works in TextPad (a shareware editor similar to Notepad++).

For the spreadsheet method, you don't necessary need to import.  If your text is tab delimited, just select all of the text and copy it to the clipboard, then paste it into a spreadsheet.